# Case Switch not operating correctly for C program

Tags: c

I have written a program in C that is to use a switch statement to calculate and display the total retail value of products 1 through 5, sold last week.  If the user enters a number other than 1 through 5, they are prompted with this: "No such product exists. Please enter a valid product number."  However, if they were to enter a two digit number such as 77, it will display this prompt twice.  If they enter a two digit number such as 36, it is displayed once.  Here is the code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

unsigned int switchfn(); // prototype function for the switch statement

    // initialize global variables
    unsigned int productOne = 0;
    unsigned int productTwo = 0;
    unsigned int productThree = 0;
    unsigned int productFour = 0;
    unsigned int productFive = 0;

// program execution
int main( void )
{   
    // retail price of each product
    double product1 = 2.98;
    double product2 = 4.50;
    double product3 = 9.98;
    double product4 = 4.49;
    double product5 = 6.87;

    // user enters data for each product on each day
    puts("Enter the product number");
    puts("Enter the quantity sold for Monday");
    unsigned int monday = switchfn();
    puts("Enter the the product number and quantity sold for Tuesday:");
    unsigned int tuesday = switchfn();
    puts("Enter the the product number and quantity sold for Wednesday:");
    unsigned int wednesday = switchfn();
    puts("Enter the the product number and quantity sold for Thursday:");
    unsigned int thursday = switchfn();
    puts("Enter the the product number and quantity sold for Friday:");
    unsigned int friday = switchfn();
    puts("Enter the the product number and quantity sold for Saturday:");
    unsigned int saturday = switchfn();
    puts("Enter the the product number and quantity sold for Sunday:");
    unsigned int sunday = switchfn();

    // display total amount of each product sold last week
    puts("\nThe total amount of each product sold is:");
    printf("Product 1: %u\n", productOne);
    printf("Product 2: %u\n", productTwo);
    printf("Product 3: %u\n", productThree);
    printf("Product 4: %u\n", productFour);
    printf("Product 5: %u\n\n", productFive);

    // display total retail cost for each product sold
    puts("\nThe total dollar amount for each product sold is:");
    printf("Product 1: %.2f\n", productOne * product1);
    printf("Product 2: %.2f\n", productTwo * product2);
    printf("Product 3: %.2f\n", productThree * product3);
    printf("Product 4: %.2f\n", productFour * product4);
    printf("Product 5: %.2f\n\n", productFive * product5);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
} // end of program

// switch function 
unsigned int switchfn()
    {
    int productNumber; // product 1 through 5

    // only while product 1 through 5 is being entered.
    while ((productNumber = getchar()) != EOF)  {

        switch (productNumber)  {

        case '1':
            ++productOne;
            break;

        case '2':
            ++productTwo;
            break;

        case '3':
            ++productThree;
            break;

        case '4':
            ++productFour;
            break;

        case '5':
            ++productFive;
            break;

        case '\n':
        case '\t':
        case ' ':
            break;

        default:
            printf("%s", "No such product exists.");
            puts("  Please enter a valid product number.");
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
    }
```

Would this involve knowing that a two digit number, and for that manner any number greater than 9 is a singular number rather than taking each digit as input?  If so, how would I implement this?  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: the posted code is reading the values digit by digit,  better to read the whole number, perhaps by `if( 1 != scanf( "%d", &productNumber ) ) { // handle error }`

Comment: Refactoring the code to eliminate the copy-paste by using functions is also _highly_ recommended,

Answer (score 1):

You are using getch () to read key input, which only reads a single keystroke at a time. When you enter 77, it is processed as 7, 7. Both of those are invalid entries, so you see you message twice. When entering 3, 6, only the 6 is an invalid entry, thus only one message is displayed.

If you want to process multiple chars as a single entry, you will need to change how you're reading it in, perhaps with a readln() or something.

Comment: readIn() does not appear to be a library function available to me

Comment: when I replace the getchar() portion of my code with scanf("%d", &productNumber), I get this for the output:Enter the product number
Enter the quantity sold for Monday
1
No such product exists.  Please enter a valid product number.
^Z
Enter the the product number and quantity sold for Tuesday:
1
No such product exists.  Please enter a valid product number.
^Z
Enter the the product number and quantity sold for Wednesday:
^Z
Enter the the product number and quantity sold for Thursday:
2

Answer (score 0):

Rather than read one `char` at a time, simple read a *line*.  Code could do all sorts of error checking on the user input before continue to the `switch()`.

```
char buf[80];
if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin)) return 0;  // Or something else to show EOF
int productNumber = atoi(buf);  // or strtol(), sscanf()

switch (productNumber)  {
    // case '1':  // Use numbers
    case 1:
        ++productOne;
        break; 
   case 2:
        ++productTwo;
        break;

   // case '\n':
   // case '\t':
   // case ' ':
```